# Lenovo ThinkPad P15 with USB-C docking station not going to sleep

Tags: lenovo-laptop, hibernate, thinkpad, external-display, docking-station

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P15 connected to a USB-C docking station, itself connected to two monitors. I do not want to use the laptop's monitor (compared to the other monitors, it is too small and its DPI is too high). Therefore I use it closed down.

This works, with at least one drawback : when I want to put it sleep (and therefore choose "Hibernate" in Windows 10) it doesn't really go to sleep. Sure, the monitors say that they are not receiving any signal anymore, but the little dot on the letter I of "ThinkPad" on the back of the closed-down monitor is still lit up and stable.

(I know this means that the laptop has not gone to sleep, because

1. after some minutes or under some conditions the fans will start revving up (and the P15 is loud, let me tell you)
2. When it is really asleep, the I-dot-LED smoothly and regularly transitions back and forth between 100% on and 100% off on (one cycle is about 4s), thus imitating the rhythm of the breathing of someone that's asleep.
3. When it really goes asleep, my Bluetooth headset will give me the "disconnect" sound.)

I tried pressing the button on top of the docking station, but it seems to have the same effect as asking it to hibernate in Windows (also it wakes it up, if asleep) - i.e. loss of signal on the monitors, but the laptop still churning away.

What could this be due to ? How to investigate ?

Comment: Try leaving the laptop monitor ON and see if the laptop sleeps properly that way,

Comment: Actually this has no impact. Sometimes it will go to sleep, sometimes it will not, and stay dark, or even the monitors will come back to life and activity will resume after some twenty seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped set in BIOS:

**Config -> Power -> Power On with AC Attach** to **Off**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).